# Issue with Bootstrap navbar. Unable to get padding on the left and right to push in the navbar image and navbar-nav links

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm expecting the navbar to have padding on the left and right per my CSS. I can't figure out after a long while trying to remove the div-container fluid, or if I'm declaring the wrong selector, I'm lost. I'm not necessarily looking for the flat-out answer, maybe a point in the right direction. I'm new to Bootstrap and still trying to wrap my head around some concepts. Where I think the problem lies is with the bootstrap classes and predefined code.

```css
.navbar {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.nav-logo {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <img class="nav-logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.jpg" alt="smart-yards-logo">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you dont want to have 'container-fluid'?

Comment: Also you should add bootstrap stylesheet links in head section, not in body

Answer (score 2):

It is a specificity weight issue. I recommend that you read into CSS specificity weight.

Bootstrap uses many selectors that create a "high" specificity to ensure that the styles apply correctly.

The easiest way to raise the specificity weight of your selector is the usage of `!important`. However, that is rarely a solution but in most cases a cover-up for the actual issue.
The best solution would be to use `nav.navbar` as selector which raises the specificity weight from `0, 1, 0` to `0, 1, 1` which in your case is sufficient to be not overwritten by Bootstrap:

```css
nav.navbar {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.nav-logo {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <img class="nav-logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.jpg" alt="smart-yards-logo">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

[tacoshy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76012075/issue-with-bootstrap-navbar-unable-to-get-padding-on-the-left-and-right-to-push/76012161#76012161) also works, and if you are wondering about specificity you can check below website. https://specificity.keegan.st/

You can also solve this by always adding your specified styles (*style.css*) in the external stylesheet below the bootstrap stylesheet link, which is the standard way you add specified styles, below is the reference

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

**Note:** Always styles that are lower in order of specification have higher priority

```css
.navbar {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.nav-logo {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Body -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <img class="nav-logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.jpg" alt="smart-yards-logo">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```